# Does "être chocolat" exist?

Tags: expressions, alimentation

I think I have read following expression somewhere:

> J'étais chocolat.

Is this an existing expression (so I remember correctly)? What does it mean?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary? Which one(s)? What did they say? What part didn't you understand?

Comment: @Gilles I looked for it on Google but did not find anything. I also asked a native French speaker but he did not know this expression.

Comment: Google is not a dictionary. The easiest freely-available dictionary, Wiktionary, has an explanation in both [French](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chocolat#Locution) and [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chocolat#Adjective). Now maybe the dictionary meaning doesn't make sense to you in context, but then you need to tell us what the context is and why the meaning from the dictionary doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: @Gilles OK, sorry, I had not thought of the fact that dictionaries also contain expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, such an expression exists in French but it is not mainstream and won't be understood by everyone.

It means to be duped, to fail something, see for example [this page](http://frenchetc.org/2014/11/14/etre-chocolat-french-expression/) and [wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_chocolat).

Beware that the same expression might be used with different meanings, for example to tell what hot beverage you like :

> – Tu veux un café ?
>   – Non merci, moi je suis chocolat.

It might also be used to tell you wear something color chocolate, or that your hairs or your skin has the same color.